# How to delete every column which has datatype string in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am doing a project which requires data cleaning. I wanted to clear columns which have strings in them.

What I planned to do is define a function and then use it. I wrote the function but it is not working. 
Here's the function:-

```
def removeStringColumns(df):
    for i in (df.columns):
        if type(df[i][0]) == "str":
            df = df.drop(df[i], axis=1)
    return df
```

And here's how I call it.

```
data = pd.read_csv("./data.csv")
data.dropna()
data = data.replace(np.nan, 0)
data = removeStringColumns(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html#pandas-dataframe-select-dtypes) and exclude 'object':

```
filtered_df = df.select_dtypes(exclude='object')
```

Or to select only numeric columns include 'number':

```
filtered_df = df.select_dtypes(include='number')
```

---

Sample `df`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'v1': np.arange(0, 10),
                   'v2': ['dog'] * 10,
                   'v3': ['cat'] * 10,
                   'v4': np.arange(10, 20)})
```

```
   v1   v2   v3  v4
0   0  dog  cat  10
1   1  dog  cat  11
2   2  dog  cat  12
3   3  dog  cat  13
4   4  dog  cat  14
5   5  dog  cat  15
6   6  dog  cat  16
7   7  dog  cat  17
8   8  dog  cat  18
9   9  dog  cat  19
```

`filtered_df`:

```
   v1  v4
0   0  10
1   1  11
2   2  12
3   3  13
4   4  14
5   5  15
6   6  16
7   7  17
8   8  18
9   9  19
```